# Draw a line with the pattern 6 point and one dash using openGL?

Tags: opengl

I want to draw a line with the pattern drawn below (6 points - one dash(:

[image]

I have read about the glLineStipple function and only find this patterns:

[image]

I even tried the code in [this](http://perso.esiee.fr/~perrotol/TheRedBook-1.0/chapter02.html) page to draw the wanted pattern with a couple of different stipple patterns but it won't work?

This is my code:

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
glLineStipple(1, 0x0101);
glLineWidth(1.5);
glBegin(GL_LINES);

glVertex2f(30, 80);
glVertex2f(40, 80);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line stipple pattern is just a 16-bit integer. So to get 6 dots followed by a short line, the pattern in binary could look like this:

```
0101010101010111
```

Splitting this into 4-bit groups gives:

```
0101 0101 0101 0111
```

And then converting each group to its hex digit:

```
0x5557
```

Which gives us the following call:

```
glLineStipple(1, 0x5557);
```